# Ansible converts strings into boolean

Tags: ansible

I have this line of code:

```
set_fact:
  my_var: "{{ (all_vars | from_yaml).metadata.annotations['features/move'] | default(omit) }}"
```

And in the template I have:

```
{% if my_var is defined %}
my_var: "{{ my_var }}"
{% endif %}
```

Expected result:

```
my_var: "true"
```

Actual result:

```
my_var: "True"
```

I found this helpful source that explains that Ansible converts strings to boolean:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11905

And I've tried the following workarounds from the above source:

```
set_fact:
  my_var: "{{ ((all_vars | from_yaml).metadata.annotations['features/move'] | default(omit)) | lower }}"
```

and

```
set_fact:
  my_var: !!str "{{ (all_vars | from_yaml).metadata.annotations['features/move'] | default(omit) }}"
```

But both still gave me "True" instead of "true". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here_ > you are using `| lower` in the variable assignation when you should use `| lower` when printing the variable: `my_var: "{{ my_var | lower }}"`

Comment: you are absolutely right! it worked! thank you so much!